# Weird doubt about complex roots of second grade equation

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I'm at the beginning of complex numbers study.
I have the following equation: $$ x^2-6i=0$$
It's a second grade eq. so I expect to get two solutions.

But: $$x=\sqrt{6}\sqrt[4]{-1}$$So I get 4 solutions.

Two of them are wrong but where's the error?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there really something like grade or is it degree?

Comment: Why do you write $i = \sqrt[4]{-1}$? Do you mean to write $x = 6\sqrt[4]{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $$i^2=-1\iff \sqrt{-1}=\pm i$$

So, by $$\sqrt[4]{-1}$$ you have included the two values of $$\sqrt[2]{-i}$$ which are [extraneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) roots of $$\sqrt[2]i$$

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood. $$\sqrt{i}=\sqrt{\sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt[4]{-1}$$. What's wrong?

Comment: @Surferonthefall, Can we write $$\sqrt1=\sqrt{\sqrt{1}}=\sqrt[4]1?$$

Comment: I think yes. and so? We are talking about root properties.

Comment: @Surferonthefall, $$\sqrt1=x\iff x^2=1\iff x=\pm1$$ and $$\sqrt[4]1=x\iff x^4=1\implies (x^2-1)(x^2+1)=0$$